# Не работает условие реакт / react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, почему не срабатывает условие?

Если убрать восклицательный знак перед условием - скрывается этот компонент, но на двух страницах, а мне нужно, чтобы он скрывался на одном варианте страницы, то есть чтобы сработало вот это:

```
const isProlongation = data?.draftId === 0;
```

Что тут не так? Спасибо!

```js
далее есть компонент с прописанным условием

 {!isProlongation && ( 
 ...
)}
```

```html
const isProlongation = data?.draftId === 0;

data приходит как пропс из другого файла и там ее значение:

 data: CalculationData | null;
 
 в CalculationData лежит это:

CalculationData {
  draftId: number | null;
  calculationDate: Date | string | null;
  ...}
```

Comment: Что значит скрывается на 2х страницах? Можете детальнее описать, как работает сейчас и какого поведения хотите достичь?

Comment: вот есть две страницы с одинаковыми компонентами - один из компонентов обернут в {!isProlongation && ( 
 ...
)} это условие, мне нужно, чтобы на одной странице он показывался, а на другой - нет. В зависимости от данных, которые получает эта переменная const isProlongation = data?.draftId === 0;

Comment: но пока что условие работает одинаково на обеих страницах = компонент либо показывается, либо скрывается

Comment: Скорее всего косяки с данными. выведите в консоль: `console.log(data, data?.draftId, data?.draftId === 0)` и посмотрите, что у вас приходит. Подозреваю, что приходит одно и тоже в 2 компонента

Comment: SwaD , дааа, нашла! получается, на одной странице одна цифра (вместо 0), а на другой (где должно быть 0 почему-то приходит другая цифра!). Проверила, заменив 0 на это число, и все сработало..))
спасибо большое!!

Comment: Когда что то идет не так, отладка сильно помогает ) Не стесняйтесь выводить данные, которые участвуют в проверке. Теперь вы умеете пользоваться console.log() )))

Comment: SwaD только теперь там данные эти меняются в зависимости от конкретного пользователя, похоже -_-
вы не знаете, как я могу найти весь список данных, которые смогут прийти в одной страницы и с другой? :D

Comment: Не зная, какую логику вы вкладываете в эти проверки и что означают сами данные, помочь, даже советом, сложновато.

Comment: понимаю! все равно большое спасибо!